# How to install kernel tools in Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, server

I want to use `lsgpio` command and other new udev gpio tools. But `lsgpio` not installed in Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15.0-45-generic). It says "lsgpio: comand not found".

How can I install `lsgpio` and other gpio kernel tools?

Comment: Are you trying to add the `lsgpio` tool cited in section 12.23 of https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.6#ACPI.2C_EFI.2C_cpufreq.2C_thermal.2C_Power_Management ?

Comment: @K7AAY yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not identical, but the **gpiod** package provides gpio discovery and control tools via the newer character device ABI:

```
sudo apt install gpiod
```

It is available in [bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gpiod). `gpiodetect` and `gpioinfo` are the basic discovery tools, while `gpioset` allows you set GPIO values.